# macrodef versus script versus javascript

Tags: javascript, ant

I want to create a task defined by a macrodef within a script element. I was hoping to find that there would be 'set' functions corresponding to each attribute. No such luck. Is there some other API for specifying the attributes?

```
 var statustask = project.createTask("service-status");
 statustask.setPath(project.getProperty("path"));
 statustask.setStatusproperty("status");
 statustask.setTimeout=("1"); // this isn't suppose to take a long time.
 statustask.perform();
```

Comment: You are using a javascript right? And you want to set the attributes or what? I am a little bit confused from your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want using methods of the [MacroInstance](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/MacroInstance.html#setDynamicAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (a subclass of Task) you'll get from the `createTask` method for a macro.  This:

```
<macrodef name="my.macro">
    <attribute name="attr1" default="NOT SET"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="attr1=@{attr1}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
    var macro = project.createTask( "my.macro" );
    macro.setDynamicAttribute( "attr1", "value_1" );
    macro.execute();
]]></script>
```

Produces this when run:

```
[echo] attr1=value_1
```

Comment: I couldn't find it in the documentation, but after much trial and error, I've determined (tested on Ant 1.7) that all `attribute` names of the `macrodef` **must** be lower case and not camel case, e.g. `<attribute name="attributeOne"/>`, or else the script (tested with JavaScript) fails with `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped Unknown attributes [attributeOne] ...` -